# Dynamically changing mobile server from meteor phonegap application

Tags: javascript, node.js, cordova, meteor

I have  one meteor 1.0 phonegap application and several meteor servers. 
According to the documentation, one can specify the server while building a phongeap cordova application https://github.com/meteor/meteor/wiki/Meteor-Cordova-Phonegap-integration
What I want to do is to set some default server and allow the users of the phonegap application to change the server from the application. How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

@MeteorAtSO I think the loadbalancer will do for you

Comment: it is not about balancing, it is about specifying completely different server, which has different data and also can have  different code for the client

Answer (score 0):

The solution for this problem was the following:

I created a package which must be loaded before any other package and which tries to read server address from localStorage. If an address is found there the package sets `__meteor_runtime_config__.DDP_DEFAULT_CONNECTION_URL = "theValueFromLocalStorage"`

Which results in that the other packages start to refer to the new server the same way as if it was set initially when building the application

The package can be found here https://github.com/partus/meteor-server-picker